# How can I convert function.bind(this) to an arrow function in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, this, arrow-functions

I want to convert my function into an arrow function but whenever I passing props it's giving me the error of undefined.

```
<TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            value={formState.inputValues.title}
            onChangeText={textChangeHandler.bind(this, "title")}
          />
```

In `onChangeText` I want to write an arrow function and pass `formState.inputValues.title` & `text` as a prop to `textChangeHandler` like this,

```
<TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            value={formState.inputValues.title}
            onChangeText={(formState.inputValues.title, text) => {
              textChangeHandler(formState.inputValues.title, text);
            }}
          />
```

textChangeHandler:

```
const textChangeHandler = (inputIdentifier, text) => {
    let isValid = false;
    if (text.trim().length > 0) {
      isValid = true;
    }
    dispatchFormState({
      type: FORM_INPUT_UPDATE,
      value: text,
      isValid: isValid,
      input: inputIdentifier,
    });
  };
```

But I am getting an error of undefined. I think I am doing it in the wrong way so how can I do it?

Comment: What is undefined for you? Also, is the definition of textChangeHandler same in both cases for you(arrow and non arrow)?

Comment: @TusharShahi If I am doing as I showed above then I am getting syntax error and If I pass only text then `textInput` field is not working correctly. Also, If not passing anything in `onChangeText` then It is showing error `Can't find variable: text`.

Comment: Firstly your function expects two arguments. When you are using bind, it is only getting one.

Comment: @TusharShahi function with bind is working fine. But I want to convert it into an arrow function. So that's what I am asking How can I do it?

Comment: Try this in your arrow function and let us know what happens textChangeHandler( text);

Comment: @TusharShahi Not working! `onChangeText={(text) =>{textChangeHandler(this,text);}}`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is onChangeText only takes one argument the changed value
[check out react-native Docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onchangetext)
Also you shouldn't need to pass in your state as you always have access to it.
The following or some variety of it should work

```
onChangeText={(text) => {
   textChangeHandler(formState.inputValues.title, text);
}}
```

You're not calling the function just creating it inline.It needs to match the signature of the prop it's being used for.

Comment: I already tried this. This is not working. `TextInput` is not working correctly. Whenever I try to add something it erases it automatically.

Comment: @HarshMishra are you getting an error? Can you add a sandbox with the complete code?

Comment: No, I am not getting any error But I am also not able to write in `TextInput` as it removes automatically.

Comment: I don't know what your state object looks like but should `value={formState.inputValues.title}` be `value={formState.inputValues.value}`